# Using ResourceDictionary in WPF outputs only "(Collection)" instead of the xaml content

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

In WPF C#, creating a main application with xaml with TabControl and importing a ResourceDictionary with a TabItem renders only the generic label "(Collection)" on the application, even on the visual studio preview.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppPOC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppPOC"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <TabControl>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="tab_input.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

tab_input.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppPOC">

    <TabItem x:Key="tab_inputs" Header="Input">
        <StackPanel>
            <GroupBox Header="Input Registers">
                <Grid>
                    <Button>Excel Import</Button>
                    <Button>Sharepoint Import</Button>
                    <Button>Choose Path</Button>
                    <ComboBox>
                        <ComboBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Red">Providers</TextBlock>
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Green">Relations</TextBlock>
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Blue">Providers Contacts</TextBlock>
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Name="pbStatus" />
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

[image: How the window looks like]

How to proper render ResourceDictionaries imported from other files?

Comment: Putting something directly into the `<TabControl>...</TabControl>` tag adds it to the Items collection of the TabControl. You have added a ResourceDictionary, so that is what the TabControl shows - in an automatically created TabItem. That said, you won't usually declare UI elements like TabItems as resources. Instead, you would create a DataTemplate for a certain type of data (i.e. a view model class). See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `TabItem` resource to the `TabControl` rather than adding the `ResourceDictionary` itself. Try this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="tab_input.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="tab_inputs" />
</TabControl>
```